# Writing MS Access .MDF files with PHP

Tags: php, database, ms-access

Is it possible to write .MDF files using PHP. I have a simple HTML table - x columns, y rows that I wish to convert into a MS Access dataset. There are no foreign keys or anything exotic, just a number of rows and columns.

I have Google searched but the only advice I seem to be able to find is to save it as a .CSV. Unfortunately this isn't acceptable for my client. They want to simply be able to double click the icon and have the database load up in Access (Seems you have to import csv files and can't just double click them).

Answer (score 0):

Those are actually two different problems:

1) Parsing HTML to separate values 
Since you seem to have found a way to export to csv, I won't be answering this. You already got your parser then.

2) Create an mdb file.

You can use odbc to talk to Access, that is, if you are in Windows. That means that PHP must be installed on a Windows machine. I'm not aware of any Linux drivers for Access..

You can use odbc_connect to connect to the database:

```
$conn = odbc_connect("dbname","" ,"");
```

From there, working with the database is pretty similar to MySQL as long as you use the ODBC functions.

The only problem is creating the actual MDB. This cannot be done in ODBC, you'll need the JET engine. It may be possible to create an MDB file from PHP, but it may be easier to create an empty MDB once, and copy that file from PHP whenever you need a new database.

Comment: Hi GolezTrol,

Yes, I am fine with parsing the data. 

Many thanks for your response but unfortunately I am running a Linux server. If there is no Linux driver then I guess I might have to put this on a windows server, however this obviously isn't the ideal situation...

Comment: No it isn't, but using Access isn't anyway. Though I wasn't aware of Linux drivers for Access, I decided to give it a go and google for it. There seem to be some attempts to create an 'access driver for linux', so you could check them out to see if they work for you.

Comment: Yeah I stumbled across a couple of drivers - unfortunately none seem to offer any write capabilities at the moment. I Think I'll have to convince them to do something with CSV. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to write an MS Access macro that would receive CSV files generated from a php script and then construct the MDF file with that information?

Answer (score 0):

Jackcess is a pure Java library for reading from and writing to MS Access databases. It is part of the OpenHMS  project from Health Market Science, Inc. . It is not an application. There is no GUI. It's a library, intended for other developers to use to build Java applications.
http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/

But an MDF file is not a standard Access file extension. MDB and MDE are while MDW is for user level security.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested this but this might help you:

http://devzone.zend.com/article/4065

Note that active development of MDB Tools has moved from Sourceforge to Github
https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools